# Comprehension of expected value$~E[X]~$where random variable$~X=1~$is held. Why it can be a total probability?

Tags: probability, expected-value

$$\underbrace{E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i P_i}_{\text{expected value}}\tag{1}$$

What I've been struggling is the following equation.

$$E[1]=1\tag{2}$$

---

$$E[X]|_{X=1}\tag{3}$$

$$=E[1]\tag{4}$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}P_{i}\tag{5}$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}1\cdot P_{i}~~\leftarrow~~\color{red}{\text{what is going on?}}\tag{6}$$

$$=1~~\leftarrow~~\text{total probability}\tag{7}$$

My thoughts are as follows.

$$X=1~~\leftarrow~~\text{Assumed that}~1~\text{is the only random variable}\tag{8}$$

$$\text{Hence}~n=1~\text{should be held}\tag{9}$$

$$E[1]=\sum_{i=1}^{1}x_{i}P_{i}\tag{10}$$

$$=x_{1}\cdot P_{1}~~\leftarrow~~\text{seems not a total probability}\tag{11}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be working with the **Law of the Unconscious Statistician** where for any function $g$: $$\mathsf E(g(X)) = \sum_{i=1}^n g(x_i)~P_i\tag 1$$

$\tiny\text{(assuming the distribution $X$ is supported over over $n$ discrete values with the indicated probability mass...)}$

So when $g(x)=1$ for all values and we have: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(1) &= \sum_{i=1}^n 1~P_i\tag 2\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n P_i\\&= 1\tag 3\end{align}$$

That is what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The mean value of a finite set of data $x_1,\ldots,x_n $ is given by

$$
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n 1}\tag1
$$

Using this idea we extend the definition of a mean for an uncountable set of data $\{x_r\}_{r\in X}$ by

$$
\frac{\int_{X}f(r)\,d r}{\int_{X}1\,d r},\quad \text{ where }f(r):=x_r\tag2
$$

Of course (2) makes sense just when $f$ is integrable. Now, a random variable is a function $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, then we set

$$
\operatorname{E}[X]:=\frac{\int_{\Omega }X(\omega )P(d\omega )}{\int_{\Omega }1P(d\omega )}=\int_{\Omega }X(\omega )P(d\omega )=\int_{\mathbb{R}}t P_X(dt)\tag3
$$

where $P_X:=P\circ X^{-1}$ is the measure in $\mathbb{R}$ induced by $X$. Then if we want to compute the mean value of $X$ in a (measurable) subset $A\subset \Omega $ with $P(A):=\int_{A}P(d\omega )>0$ then we denote it by $\operatorname{E}[X|A]$, and this would be equal to

$$
\operatorname{E}[X|A]=\frac{\int_{A}X(\omega )P(d\omega )}{\int_{A}P(d\omega )}=\frac{\operatorname{E}[X \mathbf{1}_{A}]}{P(A)}\tag4
$$

In the special case when $A=\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega )\in B\}$ for some Borel set $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ then using the induced measure $P_X$ (4) becomes

$$
\operatorname{E}[X|X\in B]=\frac{\int_{X^{-1}(B)}X(\omega )P(d\omega )}{P(X\in B)}=\frac{\int_{B}t P_X(dt)}{P(X\in B)}\tag5
$$

If the image of $X$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then the above integrals can be represented using sums, then we have that

$$
\operatorname{E}[X|X\in D]=\frac{\sum_{k\in D}k P(X=k)}{P(X\in D)}\tag6
$$

If $X$ is a constant function, that is, $X(\omega )=c$ for all $\omega \in \Omega $ for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$ then from (3) we have that

$$
\operatorname{E}[X]=\int_{\Omega }X(\omega )P(d\omega )=\int_{\Omega }cP(d\omega )=c \int_{\Omega }P(d\omega )=c\tag7
$$

Hope you see now more clear these topics.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula (1) is saying: To compute the expectation $E[X]$, multiply each possible value $x_i$ by the probability $P_i$ of that value; do this over all $n$ possible values $x_i$ for $X$, then add up.

If $X$ is a constant random variable, with constant value $1$, then there is only one possible value for $X$, namely $1$, and the probability of that value is $1$. So formula (1) has only one term in the summation, and the sum evaluates to $1\cdot 1=1$. If $X$ is a constant random variable with constant value $c$, then formula (1) gives $c$, since $n=1$ and there is one possible value $c$, and the probability of that value is $1$:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_iP_i = c \cdot 1 = c.
$$